# Strange textbook result

Tags: real-analysis

According to my textbook, if lim inf $t_n \neq \infty$, then the set $\{n | t_n < \alpha_0\}$ is infinite for $\alpha_0 >$  lim inf $t_n$

Isn't this incorrect? Doesn't the sequence $(1,1,1,1,1,1,1 \ldots)$ contradict this 'fact'?

Answer (score 3):

The set $\{n\,:\,t_n<\alpha_0\}$ is a subset of the *indices* of the sequence, not a subset of the *values* the sequence takes. For example, $\{n\,:\,t_n<2\}=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In your sequence, lim inf$=1$ so that, for $\alpha_0 >1$ there are infinitely-many terms that are less than $\alpha_0$ ; every term in the sequence satisfies that. You also have the fact that lim inf is the smallest limit point of $t_n$ by construction, so that $t_n$ clusters around lim inf.